# How can I prevent a WP7 context menu from closing after an item has been selected?

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7.1, windows-phone-7

I have hooked up a context menu item in a listbox item such that tapping it will change its state. I need either the menu to stay open after the item has been selected, or to programmatically reopen the menu right after it closes.

My menu looks like so:

```
Some Command 1
Some Command 2
Some Command 3
Inverted
```

And the user can tap the `Inverted` command and then tap one of the other commands to cause them to function in Inverted Mode, and the menu through data binding appears like so:

```
Some Command 1
Some Command 2
Some Command 3
Inverted ✔
```

Not being able to figure out how to keep the menu open after tap, I've tried the less ideal reopen menu approach like so:

```
private void onCommandInvert(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
  CommandState.Instance.Inverted = !CommandState.Instance.Inverted;

  // Open it again.
  MenuItem menuItem = (MenuItem)sender;
  ContextMenu menu = (ContextMenu)menuItem.Parent;
  menu.IsOpen = true;
}
```

But doing so throws the following exception on the `menu.IsOpen = true` statement:

```
A first chance exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in 
  System.Windows.dll

An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in 
  System.Windows.dll

Additional information: Element is already the child of another element.
```

I have also tried the following with the `Closed` event, with the same exception occurring:

```
private void onContextMenuClosed(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
  ContextMenu menu = (ContextMenu)sender;
  menu.IsOpen = true;
}
```

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: So the user holds down the first time to display the menu, and then can toggle on and off endlessly after that? Seems odd.

Comment: Also, if you look at the source for the Silverlight Toolkit, you'll see how the context menu works:   1. Take a 'screenshot' of the page. 2. scale the page * .9 3. Add the control the context menu is bound to on top of the picture. 4. Add the context menu itself. Odds are since the page actually becomes a 'screenshot', this won't be possible exactly as you're looking for. tl;dr : It seems like your UI could be rethought to no longer use a context menu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it! Thanks to willmel's comment, I digged through the source code for the `MenuItem` and was able to override `OnClick()` to do exactly what I needed (the ideal solution no doubt). I couldn't access `Click` however, so I needed to introduce a `StayClick` event property as well.

Enjoy!

```
using Microsoft.Phone.Controls;
using System.Windows;

namespace MyNamespace
{
  public class MenuItemEx : MenuItem
  {
    public bool StayOpenWhenClicked
    {
      get;
      set;
    }

    public event RoutedEventHandler StayClick;

    protected override void OnClick()
    {
      if (StayOpenWhenClicked)
      {
        if (StayClick != null)
        {
          StayClick.Invoke(this, new RoutedEventArgs());
        }
      }
      else
      {
        base.OnClick();
      }
    }
  }
}
```

and in the page's xaml, instead of `toolkit:MenuItem` you use `my:MenuItemEx`

```
<my:MenuItemEx 
  Header="Inverted"             
  StayClick="onCommandInvert"
  StayOpenWhenClicked="True"
/>
```

Comment: If you need this, I suspect your design is flawed. No user will expect this. How is he going to close the menu? If it is to stay open it is not a context menu.

Comment: The user can close the menu by selecting a different menu item other than Inverted, or by hitting the Back hw button as usual. The alternative design would be to duplicate each menu item for the inverted case and have "Some Command 1 Inverted", "Some Command 2 Inverted", "Some Command 3 Inverted" and so on, which is imho a more flawed design. I have banged my head about this for a long time and couldn't think of anything. If you have a better solution, please tell. :)

Comment: The situation you are describing sounds more like a settings page or a toggle button (near the listbox)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to persist the menu after the user has selected an item then I believe the Context menu control is not what you should be using.

Better you should create your own user control to mimic the behaviour and have it place appropriately on the screen where it makes sense (to the side or above/below)

Alternatively if these are options to be enacted on selected items consider using the application bar icons / menu items and write the event code to read the currently selected value of the listbox item.

Hope this helps.